# JSF Primefaces left, center layout

Tags: jsf, menu, primefaces

I don't understand how to display in center screen when I click button in my "left" menu.

Now I have that when I click button in my "left" menu, new page opens without "left" menu but I don't want it, I need that  "left" menu wasn't disappeared.

Below is my code.

```
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
   <frameset rows="65,*" frameborder="0">
            <frame scrolling="no" src="header.xhtml"/>
            <frameset cols="200,*" frameborder="0">
                    <frame scrolling="no" src="menu.xhtml"/>
             </frameset>
    </frameset>
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you need to give the target frame a `name` and specify it in the `target` attribute of the `<a>` element. E.g.

```
<frame name="center">
```

with

```
<a href="page.xhtml" target="center">
```

But this all is not entirely the right way to template a modern web application. Framesets have many disadvantages as to user experience and SEO valuability. Instead, the include and templating facilities of any server side view technology (like Facelets as you're using) should be used. Framesets should only be used when you have absolutely no server server side view technology at hands (thus, just plain HTML) or when you want to present an external website.

With Facelets, you should instead be using something like this as master template

`/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="header"><ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/header.xhtml"></div>
        <div id="menu"><ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/menu.xhtml"></div>
        <div id="content"><ui:insert name="content">Default content</ui:insert></div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

*(you can use CSS to position the layout components the way you want, e.g. `float:left` on `#menu` and `#content`)*

And this is how the template client (the page which you actually opens by URL) should look like:

`/page.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:define name="title">
        New page title here
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>New content here</h1>
        <p>Blah blah</p>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

For an open source example of a modern JSF/Facelets web application, check among others the [OmniFaces showcase application](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase).

As you're using PrimeFaces, there's another alternative, the `<p:layout>`. [See the "full examples" at its showcase application](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutHome.jsf), for example [this one](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutFull.jsf).

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit confusing, but I imagine that JSF templating system is what you are after, enabling you to include the same code (a menu for example) on multiple pages. Frames are very outdated and largely not used anymore.

See example at http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/

As a further comment, this issue does not seem to be related to Primefaces (which is a component pack, none of these comments are included in your code).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple header, page(s), footer example.  You can use one form id for all believe it or not.  The header goes in WebContent/templates.  The other .xhtml can go in WebContent.  If your @ManagedBean String method returns "second", the page second.xhtml will be displayed.  Each pages still talks to it's own @ManagedBean.

```
<body">
<f:view>
<div id="container">
<h:form id="templateForm">
    <div id="header">
        <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="firstId">
            <ui:insert name="first"></ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="secondId">
            <ui:insert name="second"></ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="inputMaskId">
            <ui:insert name="inputMask"></ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="valtestId">
            <ui:insert name="valtest"></ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
    </div>
</h:form>
</div>      
</f:view>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Layouts instead 
include namespace
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
<p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header=
"Top" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
<h:outputText value="Layout content for North" />
</p:layoutUnit>
<p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" header="Bottom"
resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
<h:outputText value="Layout content for South" />
</p:layoutUnit>
<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header=
"Left" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
<h:outputText value="Layout content for West" />
</p:layoutUnit>
<p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" header=
"Right" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
<h:outputText value="Layout content for Right" />
</p:layoutUnit>
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
<h:outputText value="Layout content for Center" />
</p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

This will render five panels